# Are percentages singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, numbers

- 20% of the students are/is present.
- The remaining 20% of the protein form/forms enzymes.

Singular verb or plural — which one is correct?

Answer (score 10):

When we are looking at a sentence with words that indicate portions (percent in your example, also: fraction, some...), to choose the correct subject-verb agreement, we simply have to look at the noun after "of".

In the first case, the noun is "students" - a countable noun and it is in plural, therefore the verb should be in plural as well:

> 20% of the students **are** present

Even if there are 100 students, and you want to infer 1%, you still use plural:

> 1% of 100 students **are** present

In the second case, the noun is "protein" - countable noun in singular, the verb is singular as well:

> The remaining 20% of the protein **forms** enzymes

Comment: What if it was 1% of the sudents?

Comment: Still the same, a plural is needed. Even if there were 100 students, and we knew that 1% is only one student :)

Comment: @Vilmar so much the better if you embedded your comment

Comment: @Vilmar does this still work with "100% of 1 student"?

Comment: @Ooker A rare thing to be seen in regular speech (unless we are talking about parts of the student or really formal statistics) :) In this case student is singular, so yeah, one would say "100% of 1 student is present at the exam".